# Django autocomplete-light error "'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'"

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I've installed `django-autocomplete-light` and am trying to get it to work.
I have it on the (non admin) form, but when I try to actually change the value, I get a 500 error as above.

`AttributeError at /autocomplete/SeriesAutocomplete/
'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

Here are some relevant files:

`autocomplete_light_registry.py`:

```
import autocomplete_light
from models import Series


class SeriesAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    search_fields = ['^title',],
    attrs = {'placeholder': 'Series name ?',}

autocomplete_light.register(Series, SeriesAutocomplete)
```

`forms.py`:

```
class PublicationForm(ModelForm):
    series = autocomplete_light.ModelChoiceField('SeriesAutocomplete')

    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = ['title', 'series', 'dsn', 'primary_contact', 'department']
```

I must be missing something??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a simple typo, you wrote

```
search_fields = ['^title',],
```

Which made `search_fields` a tuple of lists. Removing the comma should work.

```
search_fields = ['^title',]
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a funny bug. If you use a tuple instead of a list, i.e.

```
search_fields = ('^title',)
```

instead of

```
search_fields = ['^title',]
```

everything should work.